# Objective-C Async communication between IOS devices

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, asynchronous

Is there a way to perform async communication between  iPhones/IOS devices? I have been researching and thought maybe APN might fill that void, but it sounds like I can't initiate an APN push from an IOS dvice to another, and even if I could I can't trigger the "event" on the other device with just an APN push from what I can identify.

Does anyone have any examples or general advice for IOS device interaction for devices that are not in GameKit (i.e. wifi/bluetooth) range that does not require an intermediate service (urban airship, dedicated server, etc) or will I need to have a 3rd party in order to trigger and/or sync these interactions between devices?

Sorry I don't have any code or details as this is still in the planning phases for me. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You were given a great answer and should accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is : use a server side app and have all your devices talk to that server.

If you dont want or cannot host an app, you can use a cloud solution based on websocket like [Pusher](http://pusher.com/). You can then subscribe to events and post messages with data.

They have an iOS client library

http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries

P.S: Also have a look at [Parse](https://parse.com/) and [Stackmob](https://www.stackmob.com/) , i remember that had this kind of feature was in their roadmap, but i don't know if it's available yet..

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it and let you know what i Find.